# SwiftUI Views drifting off screen with window resizing

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, layout, alignment

I have created a rather simple SwiftUI view to use as a heading/title for my view but resizing the macOS window causes the view to drift off screen and reappear when the screen is resized again.

Here is the View.

```swift
struct Test: View {

    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8){
                    Text("TextText")
                        .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                    Text("TextText")
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                    HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline){
                        Text("TextText")
                            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                        Text("TextText")
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .thin))
                    }
                    Text("TextText")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                    Text("TextText")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                    Text("TextText")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                    Text("TextText")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                }
                .padding(30)
                .fixedSize()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Test")
    }
}
```

It is created in the detail section of a Navigation stack:

```swift
NavigationSplitView(sidebar: {
            List(selection: $selection){
                Section(header: Text("Test")){
                    Label("HomeMenuOption", systemImage: "list.and.film")
                        .tag("header")
                }
            }
        }, detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $path){
                if selection == "header" {
                    ContentView()
                }
            }
        })
```

and then I use 2 Navigation links to get to the view:

```swift
NavigationLink(value: roll, label: {
    Text("Click Me")
})                                      .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.navigationDestination(for: Roll.self) { roll in
    TestOverview(path: $path)
}
```

Then this one:

```swift
 .navigationDestination(isPresented: $moveToTest, destination: {
    Test(path: $path)
    })
```

After this the view is created but when the window is resized it drifts out of view.

[image: Gif showing the view moving off screen]

Have other people experienced this on macOS? How have you guys solved it?

I've tried things that have worked for me before like add a spacer and fixed size which are still in place but don't seem to be doing anything. Beside some basic googling I am at a loss for what to try next as my layout previously have worked in a very similar manner with no problems.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. It works fine on my machine. Please, share a copy and paste example that works out of the box. Also, are you developing using AppKit right?

Comment: Hi Mat! I haven't imported AppKit anywhere in my code so I'm quite sure it's SwiftUI, what makes you think it could be AppKit, do I have some SwiftUI stuff wrong? I am unable to reproduce the bug in another project at the moment but I will keep trying, perhaps the issue lies else where in my code....

Comment: You can use SwiftUI when building for AppKit. Let's say AppKit would be like developing for macOS native. If you go to your project > General tab you can see the destinations you are supporting. Currently macOS is available in 3 flavors: AppKit, Designed for iPad, and the old Catalyst.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! Looking here it says I'm using Mac and not Catalyst or Designed for iPad.

Comment: It should be AppKit then.